# Failed to write multilined result to text file vb.net

Tags: vb.net, multiline

I have this function which return all TCP connections for all proccess

```
Declare Auto Function GetExtendedTcpTable Lib "iphlpapi.dll" (ByVal pTCPTable As IntPtr, ByRef OutLen As Integer, ByVal Sort As Boolean, ByVal IpVersion As Integer, ByVal dwClass As Integer, ByVal Reserved As Integer) As Integer
Const TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL As Integer = 5
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Public Structure MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID
    Public NumberOfEntries As Integer 'number of rows
    Public Table As IntPtr 'array of tables
End Structure
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Public Structure MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID
    Public state As Integer 'state of the connection
    Public localAddress As UInteger
    Public LocalPort As Integer
    Public RemoteAddress As UInteger
    Public remotePort As Integer
    Public PID As Integer 'Process ID
End Structure
Structure TcpConnection
    Public State As TcpState
    Public localAddress As String
    Public LocalPort As Integer
    Public RemoteAddress As String
    Public remotePort As Integer
    Public Proc As String
End Structure
Function GetAllTCPConnections() As MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID()
    GetAllTCPConnections = Nothing
    Dim cb As Integer
    GetExtendedTcpTable(Nothing, cb, False, 2, TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL, 0)
    Dim tcptable As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(cb)
    If GetExtendedTcpTable(tcptable, cb, False, 2, TCP_TABLE_OWNER_PID_ALL, 0) = 0 Then
        Dim tab As MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID = Marshal.PtrToStructure(tcptable, GetType(MIB_TCPTABLE_OWNER_PID))
        Dim Mibs(tab.NumberOfEntries - 1) As MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID
        Dim row As IntPtr
        For i As Integer = 0 To tab.NumberOfEntries - 1
            row = New IntPtr(tcptable.ToInt32 + Marshal.SizeOf(tab.NumberOfEntries) + Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID)) * i)
            Mibs(i) = Marshal.PtrToStructure(row, GetType(MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID))
        Next
        GetAllTCPConnections = Mibs
    End If
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(tcptable)
End Function
Function MIB_ROW_To_TCP(ByVal row As MIB_TCPROW_OWNER_PID) As TcpConnection
    Dim tcp As New TcpConnection
    tcp.State = DirectCast(row.state, TcpState) 'a State enum is better than an int
    Dim ipad As New IPAddress(row.localAddress)
    tcp.localAddress = ipad.ToString
    tcp.LocalPort = row.LocalPort / 256 + (row.LocalPort Mod 256) * 256
    ipad = New IPAddress(row.RemoteAddress)
    tcp.RemoteAddress = ipad.ToString
    tcp.remotePort = row.remotePort / 256 + (row.remotePort Mod 256) * 256
    Dim p As Process = Process.GetProcessById(row.PID)
    tcp.Proc = p.ProcessName
    p.Dispose()
    Return tcp
End Function
```

I wan't to store only the out going connections of certain processes in a text file so I used

```
Sub main()
    For Each Row In GetAllTCPConnections()
        Dim Tcp As TcpConnection = MIB_ROW_To_TCP(Row)
        Dim RemoteAddress As String = Tcp.RemoteAddress.ToString
        Dim process As String = Tcp.Proc
        If (process = "chrome" Or process = "Viber" Or process = "ddns") And (RemoteAddress <> "127.0.0.1") And (RemoteAddress <> "0.0.0.0") Then
            Dim myFile As String = "C:\TCP.txt"
            Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(myFile)
                Dim line As String = Tcp.RemoteAddress & "|" & Tcp.localAddress & "|" & Tcp.LocalPort & "|" & Tcp.Proc
                    sw.WriteLine(line)
                    MsgBox(line)
            End Using
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

msgbox works fine showing every process and out going connections that established by it but when I open

> TCP.txt

file I only find one line. 
So how to write the entire results (Each process with its out going connections) to the text file?

Comment: use `Environment.NewLine`?

Comment: you open a new Stream inside your for each loop; you dont tell SW to append, so it is probably overwriting the previous items leaving just the last one there.  MsgBox is just showing which item is active in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the append to text file.

You need to change:
Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(myFile)
To
Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(myFile, True)

By setting the true you set the append to file to true